# Lockscreen Widget is too Small

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm having a lot of trouble finding references for lockscreen widgets that were introduced in Android 4.2.

I've created a widget that works fine on the launcher and it is sized as I expect. However I've enabled this widget to be on the lockscreen and it doesn't size properly, vertically.

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen it will take up the size available vertically if you set `android:resizeMode="vertical"`

> If the widget marks itself as vertically resizable, then the widget
>   height shows up as "small" on portrait phones displaying an unlock UI.
>   In all other cases, the widget sizes to fill the available height.

Also I used the sizing described at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html

**Tiles > Size**

- 1 > 40dp
- 2 > 110dp
- 3 > 180dp
- 4 > 250dp
- … > …
- n > 70 × n − 30

I've set this and at appears to be even smaller than a "small" widget. Basically, does anyone know what is wrong with the widget in *image 1* that it won't expand? My code is below.

1) What it looks like in its default state.

[image]

2) What it looks like when expanded on another screen.

[image]

**xml/clock_widget.xml**

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/clock_widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/clock_widget"
    android:minHeight="110dp"
    android:minWidth="180dp"
    android:resizeMode="vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"
    android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen" >

</appwidget-provider>
```

**layout/clock_widget.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/clock_widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_hour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=":"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_minute"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try to add minHeight to root LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this only happens in the emulator. Testing on real hardware works fine.

Comment: Well, I have seen this problem in a Genymotion virtual device with my widget, and asked a person with a smartphone with a similar configuracion and the problem persists. Which phone are you talking about when you say "real hardware"?

Comment: It works fine under a Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 4, and Nexus 7. It didn't work on an emulator of the configuration of a Galaxy Nexus

Comment: Strange... all those devices come with the stock launcher. Are you saying that your widget looks like the one in image 2 all the time? AFAIK the initial display is small on portrait phones, and once you swipe down the lock it expands

Comment: The widget is the proper size as in image 2. The issue was that it was supposed to be the size in image 2, but for some reason it is cut off in the emulator so I just developed on the phone.